# need to disable ctrlH

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-xp

i've been able to disable ctrl shift delete and also from under safety tab however, when you press ctrl h or click favourites and then history you can still delete.

i need to know how to block this feature.

i've tried looking on google and that tells me to 
DisableDeleteBrowsingHistory dword set value as 1, all what that does is blocks ctrl alt del.

using ie8 on xp pro

any help on blocking ctrlH delete would be appreciated

Comment: just curious...why? is this to keep tabs on your employees or something? wouldn't it be better to find a way to send their browsing history to some central server with their userid?

Comment: don't know how to do that, this "seemed" to be a simpler option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to block that key combination when IE is up, you can use an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script. However, the user could still click to open History and then delete, right?

AutoHotkey script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode,2
#IfWinActive Windows Internet Explorer
   ^H::
return
```

Comment: thats what i'm trying to et ride of, being able to delete histroy,

both ctrlH and right click on histroy.